# dotnet-trace and WaitForSignal - how to interpret results?

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

I have few ASP .Net Core apps that runs in kubernetes.

I am trying to optimize them by finding what consumes most of the CPU.

When I run `dotnet-trace` it seems like majority of the CPU is spend on `System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal(int)`.

[image]

Please note that I am not using any semaphores myself, however I use a lot of `async` and `await Task.WhenAll(...)`. I also don't use `Task.Run(...)`.

The `dotnet-trace` was taken from real production pod, that serves around 25 requests/sec, and each request is calling a DB and an external API.

My questions:

1. Where does this `WaitForSignal` come from?
2. Does the `WaitForSignal` really consumes CPU?
3. Is using `Task.WhenAll` or `async/await` confuse `dotnet-trace`?
4. How to measure/trace what really consumes CPU?
5. What does the last column "**Category**" mean? (`Database | Json | Serialization`)